# How to move down an div element with second level div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var $selectd = $();
var itemLv1 = $("#create-summary .lv1"); 
$(itemLv1).click(function(){
    $selectd = $(this);
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked');
});

$("#moveDown").click(function(){
    $selectd.add($selectd.nextUntil(":not(.lv2)"))
            .insertAfter($selectd.nextAll(".lv1:first"))
});
```

```css
.clicked {
    background-color:red;
}

.lv2 {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="create-summary">
            <div class="lv1">1. AAA</div>
            <div class="lv1">2. BBB</div>
            <div class="lv1">3. CCC</div>
            <div class="lv2">3.1 111</div>
            <div class="lv2">3.2 222</div>
            <div class="lv2">3.3 333</div>
            <div class="lv1">4. DDD</div>
            <div class="lv1">5. EEE</div>
          </div>

<button type="button" id="moveDown">Down </button>
```

When I click on "CCC", it will move down with its second level div.

However, I click on "BBB" to move down, it will move after only "CCC" without "CCC" second level div.

How to do to make "BBB" to move after whole CCC include CCC second level(111, 222, 333 div)

Comment: You should nest the DIVs to match the levels, instead of putting them all on the same DOM level.

Comment: @RomanC why did you edit out the working code snippet?

Comment: @Barmar How do you think, why am I edited this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly nest the elements into their own containers so that each of the elements are at the same level.

**HTML**

```
<div id="create-summary">
    <div class="lv1">
        <div class="title">1. AAA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lv1">
        <div class="title">2. BBB</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lv1">
        <div class="title">3. CCC</div>
        <div class="lv2">3.1 111</div>
        <div class="lv2">3.2 222</div>
        <div class="lv2">3.3 333</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lv1">
        <div class="title">4. DDD</div>
    </div>
    <div class="lv1">
        <div class="title">5. EEE</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="moveDown">Down</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.lv2 {
    margin-left:10px;
}
.clicked .title {
    background-color:red;
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dz6sLd9/)**